# Is there built-in web analytics tool in Liferay?

Tags: portlet, liferay, web-analytics

I need to have the statistics of a web site and generate reports. I am using Liferay portal. Is there anything built-in for web analytics in Liferay? if yes, please help how to configure it?

Thanks,
Dhananjay

Answer (score 5):

I think adding Google Analytics to your portal's theme is your best bet. How to do that [is described here](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Google+Analytics).

Comment: I do have google analytics for my application. The problem is that i need page wise information.Like number of visits to website, number of people who logged in sucessfully number of people who saw "about us" page, like that...
Is this possible in google analytics?
If so please help me with this..

Comment: How do i view page level counts in Google Analytics? I have 10 jsp's i need to have data of how many people visied each page..
How do i get it?
I hav added google analytics generated Javascript in all d JSPs.

Comment: Adding Google Analytics to portal's theme will get only the data at theme level. I have used a custom theme for the whole web site.

Comment: This is not true. One little script that invokes Google Analytics (which you just add to your theme so it is inserted into the code just before </body> on *every page*) is enough to see all the information you need. No need to add specific tagging information to specific pages.

Look here: http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55488&utm_source=DiscoverList&utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=en_us&hl=en

Just give it a try, you will find it out hands-on.

Comment: Hi.. I don't know how to figure out the pagevisits based on indiidual pages of my website. Like number of visits to home page (URL for home page), number of visits to offer page and so on..

Comment: how do categorize the counts. now the report looks lik this-
Visits

·         1,867 

Pageviews

·         9,383 

Pages/Visit

·         5.03 

Bounce Rate

·         27.85% 

Avg. Time on Site

·         00:05:36 

% New Visits

·         45.31%

Comment: i think your question is answered now

Answer (score 2):

I've put together a short tutorial on setting up Google Analytics and Google Webmaster Tools in the latest version of Liferay.  It's very straight forward gives you tonnes of feedback on who's accessing your site. Hope it's of use to you: [Google Webmaster Tools and Google Analytics in Liferay](http://www.greatwhiteit.com/web/guest/home/-/blogs/google-webmaster-tools-and-google-analytics-in-liferay)

Comment: I believe your link has been hijacked or either your domain registration has expired.

Answer (score 2):

Liferay has first class support for Google-Analytics, if you want to moniter entire site with one GA ID its there and also it supports if you want to monitor each community with different GA ID.

You can set this on every community, go to

Settings > Monitor >

and set your GA IDs